# mongo php library updateOne & insertOne damaging collection

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an application I am trying to update from legacy to new driver. I am having a problem with collections being damaged when the below code is triggered. I think I have narrowed it down here.

```
    function update($collection,$criteria,$data,$insertIfNotExists = false)
{
    if(!empty($collection) && !empty($criteria) && !empty($data)) {
        if (!isset($this->collection[$collection])) {
            $this->collection[$collection] = (new MongoDB\Client)->hebe->{$collection};
        }
        if ($insertIfNotExists) {
            $oldData = $this->collection[$collection]->findOne($criteria);
            if ($oldData == NULL) {
                $data['createdDate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $data['modifiedDate'] = (isset($data['modifiedDate'])) ? $data['modifiedDate']:date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                /*
                return ($this->collection[$collection]->insertOne($data)) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
                */
            } else {
                $newData = $oldData;
                foreach($data as $n=>$v) {
                    $newData[$n] = $v;
                }
                $newData['modifiedDate'] = (isset($newData['modifiedDate'])) ? $newData['modifiedDate']:date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                /*
                return ($this->collection[$collection]->updateOne($criteria,['$set' => $newData])) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
                */
            }
        } else {
            /*
            return ($this->collection[$collection]->updateOne($criteria,['$set' => $data])) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
            */
        }
    }

}
```

example variables are

```
$collection = 'customer'

$criteria = array ( 'number' => '9999',)

$data = array (
  'number' => '9999',
  'name' => 'Testing Account',
  'reference' => 'Peter Smith',
  'defaultDeliveryAddress' => 1,
  'visitAddress' => '',
  'address' => '',
  'district' => 'Marknad',
  'postAddress' => '',
  'orgNumber' => '5562041771',
  'phone' => '031-7802700',
  'fax' => '031-193328',
  'groupCode' => 'int',
  'creditCustomer' => '',
  'typeOfDelivery' => 'Bil',
  'typeOfPayment' => '10',
  'emailAddresses' => 
  array (
    'invoice' => 'email1@domain.com',
    'order' => 'email2@domain.com',
    'deliveryNote' => 'email3@domain.com',
    'packingSlip' => 'email4@domain.com',
  ),
  'orderType' => NULL,
  'termsOfDelivery' => 'RC',
  'creditLimit' => 100000.0,
  'pricelist' => 4,
  'pricelist1' => '',
  'pricelist2' => '9998',
  'pricelist3' => '104',
  'discount' => NULL,
  'countryCode' => 'SE',
  'currencyCode' => 'SEK',
  'blocked' => 0,
  'deliveryCost' => 0,
  'vatCode' => '2',
  'email' => 'peremail@domain.com',
  'password' => 'password',
  'modifiedDate' => '2019-06-25 00:00:00',
  'deliveryAddresses' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'row' => 1,
      'name' => 'Test Address',
      'address' => 'Box 12345',
      'postAddress' => '42246',
      'default' => true,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'number' => '9999',
      'name' => 'Testing Address',
      'reference' => '13232',
      'address' => 'Box 12245',
      'postAddress' => '42246',
    ),
  ),
  'references' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'number' => '9999',
      'name' => 'Testing',
      'email' => '',
      'password' => '',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'number' => '9999',
      'name' => 'Testing2',
      'email' => '',
      'password' => 'password',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'number' => '9999',
      'name' => 'Peter Smith',
      'email' => '',
      'password' => 'password',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on what I am doing wrong with `updateOne` and `insertOne`. From what I understand by the docs is it supports array.

EDIT: a little background is I upgraded this system and MongoDB from 2.6 to 3.6. I also upgraded mongodb driver from legacy mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the old data in the collection had quotations and the updateOne/insertOne data did not. Correcting this seem to solve the problem.